# Times series data input as X and 3d continuous data as target Y - Regression using RNN ( LSTM & GRU )

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression, recurrent-neural-network

actually i'm trying to build a RNN using LSTM or GRU for regression.
My Input data are time series from Imu Sensor and my Target data are (x,y,z),
Well to be precise I'm trying to predict the PAD values from time series(pleasure,arousal and dominance).
So for each time series folder i have the corresponding PAD values
X=[-1.1546,-2.55...,N] Y = [-0.5,0.6, 0.3]
I know that LSTM need 3d input for instence (1,x,y), for the input it is okay,
But the problem is with Target, do you think I need to reshape the 3d target as same as input?
or do you have any idea to deal with my problem?
X = Time Series and Y = (x,y,z)

Thank you in advance for your answers or any suggestion !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape only tour input(batch_size, timesteps, features), but your target shape depends on what you put after your LSTM, or what kind of output you choose for your LSTM.

Suppose you have a LSTM that outputs n neurons, if you choose to set return_sequences = False, it will have an ouput like this : (batch_size, n) (one output per sequence).

If you choose to set return_sequences = True, it will output a sequence the same size as the input, so you will have an output this shape : (batch_size , timesteps, n).

In the first case, your output is directly 2d so you don't need to reshape your target. If you decide to use return_sequences = True, you will need to find a way to reshape the output of the LSTM (There is multiple layers in Keras that allows you to alter the shape of the output of a previous layer).

Comment: No problem ! Can you validate the answer ?

Comment: Sure !
I have an other question,
I'm trying to stack 2 GRU layers , when return_sequence is true it is okay , when i change return_sequence to false i have this error :
 str(K.ndim(x)))

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer gru_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: That's normal since a RNN needs a sequence as an inout. When you set return_sequences to False your first layer does not return one so the second layer doesn't get the rught type of input.